# Python inspect.stack()'s code_context only returns one line of context

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect

```
import inspect

def a(x, y, z):
  frame = inspect.stack()[1]
  print(frame.code_context)

def b():
  a(
    1,
    2,
    3,
  )

b()

>> ['    3,\n']
```

Why is code_context only returning the last line??
The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) says code_context is "*a list of lines of context from the source code*"

I would expect the code_context to include something along the lines of:

```
[
  '    1,\n',
  '    2,\n',
  '    3,\n',
]
```

I would like to obtain *all* lines of context.

Answer (score 2):

The Python interpreter retains only a single line number for each frame unfortunately. One relatively easy and robust way to seeing the entire code context is by decompiling the code object using the excellent [`uncompyle6`](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/) module. Since the code object does not retain white spaces and comments, you'll see the more compact version of your original code as the decompiled output:

```
import inspect
from io import StringIO
from uncompyle6 import deparse_code2str

def a(x, y, z):
    frame = inspect.stack()[1]
    code = StringIO()
    deparse_code2str(frame.frame.f_code, out=code)
    print(code.getvalue())

def b():
    a(
        1,
        2,
        3,
    )

b()
```

This outputs:

```
a(1, 2, 3)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/PastelPunyProcess

Comment: uncompyle6 and decompile3 also allow you to deparse based on an offset and work your way up its parse tree. So in that sense you can get as little or as much context as you desire, including grammar symbols if you so choose. https://rocky.github.io/pycon2018.co/#/13 shows a little of this.

Answer (score 2):

For a robust solution that preserves white spaces and comments, you can use the `lib2to3` module to parse and scrape all the simple statement nodes (denoted by `simple_stmt` in the Python grammar from [Grammar.txt](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/Grammar.txt)) from the file the parent frame belongs to, and return the node whose starting line number and the number of lines (calculated by counting the number of newline characters) cover the line number of the frame. Note that the statement node does not contain the preceding indentation if it's at the beginning of a code block, however, so you would have to obtain the indentation from its previous sibling node if it is a node of white spaces:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor

class StatementScraper(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = 'simple_stmt'

    def __init__(self, lineno):
        super().__init__(None, None)
        self.lineno = lineno
        self.statement = ''

    def transform(self, node, result):
        if not self.statement and self.lineno - node.get_lineno() < str(node).count('\n'):
            prev_sibling = str(node.prev_sibling)
            if prev_sibling.isspace():
                self.statement += prev_sibling.lstrip('\n')
            self.statement += str(node)
        return node

class get_statement(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def __init__(self, source, lineno):
        self.source = source
        self.scraper = StatementScraper(lineno)
        super().__init__(None)

    def get_fixers(self):
        return [self.scraper], []

    def __str__(self):
        self.refactor_string(self.source, '')
        return self.scraper.statement
```

so that:

```
import inspect

def a(x, y, z):
    frame = inspect.stack()[1].frame
    print(get_statement(open(frame.f_code.co_filename).read(), frame.f_lineno))

def b():
    a(
        1,
        2,
        3,
    )

b()
```

outputs:

```
    a(
        1,
        2,
        3,
    )
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/HotpinkOpenCgibin